# Custom CSS Input Field issue

Tags: html, css

Why does my cursor start top right in this example?

See when I click inside the field, it's top right then when I type it moves to the centre. Any ideas why?

http://jsfiddle.net/2Ltm5adw/

**HTML:**

```
<label class="input">
    <span>Email address</span>
    <input type="text" />
</label>
```

**CSS:**

```
input, select, textarea {
    line-height:50px;
    width:100%;
    padding-left:20px;
    display: block;
}

.input span {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  cursor: text;
  pointer-events: none;
  color: #999;
  /* Input padding + input border */
  padding: 7px;
  /* Firefox does not respond well to different line heights. Use padding instead. */
  line-height: 50px;
  /* This gives a little gap between the cursor and the label */
  margin-left: 2px;
}

.input input, .input textarea, .input select {
  z-index: 0;
  padding: 6px;
  margin: 0;
  font: inherit;
  line-height: 50px;
}
```

Comment: on FF it sits center - but i bet it's how some browsers render the `line-height`, why aren't you using `placeholder="Email"`?

Comment: remove`line-height: 50px;` set `height` instead

Comment: input type='email' will do some basic checks to see if the formatting is correct

Comment: **Some people are confused with your goal.**
I guess you are just trying to style the standard input instead of creating your own input.

As said by others, there's an issue in the `line-height` with some browsers. You can use `height` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of the `line-height`. Replace it with `height`:

```css
input,
select,
textarea {
  border: 2px solid $gray-lighter;
  border-bottom: 1px solid $gray-lighter;
  border-top: 1px solid $gray-lighter;
  height: 50px;
  /*replace with height*/
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 20px;
  background: $white;
  display: block;
}
.input span {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  cursor: text;
  pointer-events: none;
  color: #999;
  /* Input padding + input border */
  padding: 7px;
  /* Firefox does not respond well to different line heights. Use padding instead. */
  line-height: 50px;
  /* This gives a little gap between the cursor and the label */
  margin-left: 2px;
}
.input input,
.input textarea,
.input select {
  z-index: 0;
  padding: 6px;
  margin: 0;
  font: inherit;
  height: 50px;
  /*replace height*/
}
```

```html
<label class="input">
  <span>Email address</span>
  <input type="text" />
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GopsAB/2Ltm5adw/1/)

It's because of line-height. try height instead line-height.It works fine

```
.input input, .input textarea, .input select {
 z-index: 0;
 padding: 6px;
 margin: 0;
 font: inherit;
 height: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `line-height` from inputs and replace them with `padding: 20px 7px;`

```css
.input span {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  cursor: text;
  pointer-events: none;
  color: #999;
  /* Input padding + input border */
  padding: 7px;
  /* Firefox does not respond well to different line heights. Use padding instead. */
  line-height: 50px;
  /* This gives a little gap between the cursor and the label */
  margin-left: 2px;
}
.input input,
.input textarea,
.input select {
  z-index: 0;
  padding: 6px;
  margin: 0;
  font: inherit;
  padding: 20px 7px;
}
```

```html
<label class="input">
  <span>Email address</span>
  <input type="text" />
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your updated [**`JSFiddle Link`**](http://jsfiddle.net/2Ltm5adw/3/), Check out your issue has been solved or not !!

**Changes Made:**

```
.input span {
  padding: 20px;
  line-height: 25px;
}
.input input, .input textarea, .input select {
  padding: 20px;
  height: 25px;
}
```

Comment: Please ensure to include information in your answer as to what you have done to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Whats wrong with this ? Saves mucking around

```html
<label for="emailID">Email Address : </label>
    
    <input type="email" id="emailID" placeholder="Your Email Address"/>
```

And stylable.

```css
#emailID {width:300px;background-color:green;color:white;border-radius:5px;}
```

```html
 <label for="emailID">Email Address : </label>
        
        <input type="email" id="emailID" placeholder="Your Email Address"/>
```